# get_the_post_thumbnail_url() Откуда берёт адрес?как добавить изображение?

Tags: wordpress

```
<img alt="<?php  $post->ID; ?>" src="<?php  get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
```

Код в файле blog-template.php. Как загрузить изображение в пост, чтобы функция получила ссылку на него?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите изображение записи в админке. Его url и будет выведен по `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня не предлагает такого. Возможно нужен плагин?

Comment: Это самый что ни на есть стандартный функционал WordPress

Comment: Тогда что сделать чтобы появилась такая форма? Т.к.её у меня нет. Версия WP последняя

Comment: Вверху есть Настройки экрана -> Изображение записи. http://take.ms/PEU2c Поставьте там галочку. Но по умолчанию эта возможность включена. Деактивируйте все плагины, если не увидите этого чекбокса.

Comment: Простите.Но нет такого

Comment: Так не бывает. Сносите весь тот хлам, что понаставили на WP сверху, включите стандартную тему - и увидите. Или установите WP с нуля. Изображение записи - абсолютно базовый функционал, с самых первых версий WP.

Comment: Да, и еще вопрос - вы запись со страницей не путаете?

Comment: конечно не путаю) хорошо, спасибо, попробую

Comment: действительно проблема в теме. почему-то своя тема не пускает этот блок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77674/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).